# How to get the matched fields from two collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections called "orders" and "items" as specified below:

```
db.orders.insert([
   { "_id" : 1, "item" : "almonds", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 },
   { "_id" : 2, "item" : "pecans", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 }
])

db.items.insert([
  { "_id" : 1, "item" : "almonds", description: "almond clusters", "instock" : 120 },
  { "_id" : 2, "item" : "bread", description: "raisin and nut bread", "instock" : 80 },
  { "_id" : 3, "item" : "pecans", description: "candied pecans", "instock" : 60 }
])
```

Now, I'm trying to fetch the document if the "item" field gets matched in both the collections.

I have tried using $lookup operator for this scenario, but somehow the query is getting failed when tried to run on the mongo shell.

## My $lookup query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "items",
         localField: “item”,
         foreignField: “item”,
         as: "ite"
       }
  },
  { $unwind: "$ite" },
  {
    $project: {
        “item”: 1
     }
  }
])
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding the above mentioned scenario ...

Comment: Can you add your query to the post ?

Comment: Hi Veeram, I had added my quey to the post

Comment: I see the non-ascii character double quotation mark (“”) vs quotation mark("). Replace with "

Comment: Thanks a lot Veeram. Now, I'm able to run the query.